# Minimum tick interval (monthly) not working for datetime Highchart graph

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I am working with date-time highchart and I want x-axis tick interval to appear every month`(jan-12, Feb-12, Mar-12)`. But If the data points are less than 4 then the x-axis label starts showing days of month as well `(10 dec,24 dec, 7 jan)`. How do I make sure that even if there are less data points or the graph is zoomed, the tick interval are monthly. Here is the code for x-axis:

```
xAxis : {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickmarkPlacement:'on',
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                            month: '%b-%y',
                            },
                        minRange:1*30*24*60*60*1000,
                        labels : {
                            rotation :'280',
                            align:'right',
                            style: {
                                fontFamily : 'Helvetica',
                                fontSize: '10px'
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner). If you will have problems with implementing or would like to find another solution, then please post a live example of your issue, e.g. in JSFiddle.

Comment: I don't want to define tick positions by myself. I want high chart to decide it. However i don't want ticks for days of month.

Comment: If you want to have Highcharts deciding differently than they do now, then you could extend HC - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts If you think this is a bug, and it should be fixed then please post a live demo.

Comment: Your title says the tick interval isn't working, but you haven't specified a tick interval in the code you've posted.  Set your **tickInterval** to 30 days, and it should work as you've described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set PointIntervals per month in HighChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963429/how-to-set-pointintervals-per-month-in-highchart)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my earlier comment, the easiest way to get what you've asked for is to set the tickInterval:

```
xAxis: { 
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval:86400000 * 30
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Lmfa5v55/

With this setup it doesn't matter what interval your data is in - in the example, it's daily - or if it's irregularly spaced or not.

It doesn't matter what level of zoom, or how many data points, you'll have a tick and label for each month within the bounds of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try put exact interval tick, and automatic day or month will appear.

You only need format label, after put ticks.

```
      Options.xAxis.tickPositioner = function () {
        const ticks = this.series[0].xData;
        let result = [];

        for (let index = 0; index < ticks.length; index++) {
          result.push(ticks[index]);
        }
        return result;
      };
```

and format xAxis
labels: {
format: "{value:%b-%Y}",
align: "center"
}

to tooltips
tooltip: {
valueSuffix: "",
valuePrefix: "",
xDateFormat: "%B - %Y",
valueDecimals: 0
},

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that not all the months have 30 days, is better not to set the tickInterval or the minRange. You could try to generate the months at your own, like:

```
startDate = Date.UTC(2012, 1, 1); //your starting date
// Set the xaxis value as first day of month
for (var i = 0; i < yourData.length; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(startDate);
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + i);
    categories.push(d.getTime());
}
```

Or generate your own categories as shown on Highcharts demo page:

```
xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec' //etc.
            ],
        },
```

See a working demo of first option at: http://jsfiddle.net/gjkde5np/1/

Extracted from: [How to set PointIntervals per month in HighChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963429/how-to-set-pointintervals-per-month-in-highchart)

You could also check the code from highcharts "Time series with irregular intervals" http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time . Here they use the `[Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0], [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 4), 0.28]`

Comment: While it's obviously true that not all months have 30 days, if you set your tickInterval to 30 days, the result will be an axis label for each month. If absolute precision is required, you could calculate each month and use tickPositions or tickPositioner, but the poster already said they don't want to do that.

Comment: Additionally, if you look at the result in the fiddle you've posted, it doesn't achieve what the origin post asked for - there is not a label for each month; you've instead manipulated the x values for the data itself, and if you look at the actual values, they are not the first of each month, they are 30 days apart :)

Comment: You are right with the absolute precision, but in the question, they ask for 1 month each value, in the fiddle, if you change the data to 4 values only, each point is 1 month apart of each other (as they asked).